# Why there is no change in my order Table while it shows the change in my DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, linq-to-sql, datagridview

I want to use Linq to manipulate data in my local DB, northWind

I have following the [Creating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233763%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [connecting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171890%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) processes of MSDN

I have created NorthWind.dbml linq file and drop the two tables in it:

[image]

After that I write this code in my form to retrieve data and to add new data to my data base:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LinqToSql_Ders
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Load += Form1_Load;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            show();
            comboBoxItems();
        }
        NorthWindDataContext db = new NorthWindDataContext();
        private void show()
        {

            var linqCommand = from order in db.Orders
                              join cust in db.Customers
                              on order.CustomerID equals cust.CustomerID
                              select new
                              {
                                  order.OrderID,
                                  order.OrderQuantity,
                                  order.OrderDate,
                                  cust.CustomerID,                                 
                              };
            dataGridView1.DataSource = linqCommand;
        }

        void comboBoxItems()
        {
            var linqCommand = from cust in db.Customers
                              select cust;
            orderCombBox.DataSource = linqCommand;
            orderCombBox.ValueMember = "CustomerID";
            orderCombBox.DisplayMember = "CustomerID";
        }
        private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Order ord = new Order();
            ord.OrderID = int.Parse(orderIDTextField.Text);
            ord.OrderQuantity = int.Parse(nudquantityfield.Value.ToString());
            ord.CustomerID = orderCombBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
            ord.OrderDate = dateTimePicker.Value;
            db.Orders.InsertOnSubmit(ord);
            db.SubmitChanges();
            show();
        }

    }
}
```

It shows the already added columns in the right way
[image]

When I add a new item, the dataGridView show that it is added 
but when I view the table "order" data, it shows nothing (there isn't any new record added)
[image] 
[image]

Is there any wrong with the code I use, especially the DB part:

```
db.Orders.InsertOnSubmit(ord);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

or how can I solve my problem?

Comment: Where are placed your database files? Do you copy them do `bin` direcotry each time you run the program?

Comment: @roman, not me but each time the program is running, `Northwind.mdf` and `Northwind_log.ldf` are created (even when I deleted them befor running), is this the problem and how to solve it ?

Comment: It is possible that your code works fine, but you can't get the latest values from database. Make sure that Visual Studio data table editor is connected to the valid database. You can disable copying database: file -> properties -> copy to output directory -> copy if newer

Comment: @roman, I guess so, but how can I get the latest value from the DB

Comment: @roman, thanks that fix the problem, but how can I copy the changes from the file in the `/bin` to the original file, could you tell me about this and add your suggestion as an answer so I can accept it,

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders Regarding flags... this question is more about the Visual Studio problems with the database than linq. In fact, it has nothing to do with linq. So 'visual-studio' and 'database' flags should be a little more appropriate, IMO.

Comment: @roman:  
[tag:database] is still far too general, and you may not be aware of it, but [tag:linq] is also too general. The OP is using LINQ to SQL, so that tag is appropriate. I put back [tag:visual-studio], and, FYI, you could have done that yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine, but you are not able to get the latest values from the database using the Visual Studio data table editor.

Every time you run the application the database files are copied to the `bin` folder. You can disable this behavior by selecting the database file in Solution Explorer and changing the "Copy to output directory" option to "Copy if newer" or (even better) to "Do not copy" (after the first run). Later, if you would like to modify the structure of the database you have to copy paste the database file from the `bin` directory to the project directory, modify it under the Visual Studio editor, and copy it back.

The best option is to place the database files outside of your project and to set the valid connection string (in the config file) to this new location.

Useful links:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246989.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233817.aspx